# How to show system menu of a file in C#

Tags: c#, menu, window, system

I need to show system menu of a file in my application. This menu same as the image.
[image]

And, I also want to add a my menu element to this menu.

How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: search for shell extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a *shell context menu*. To display such a menu in your application, you'll have to call the Windows API. This is not at all easy, but fortunately for you some other people have taken a stab at it.

The [C# File Browser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15059/C-File-Browser) on CodeProject has a shell context menu, which is also described in that article.

Then [Andreas Johansson](http://windows-tech.info/19/e5ad8751fc63816b.php) extracted the shell context menu code from that project and uploaded it as a separate ZIP file, which you can [download here](http://members.chello.nl/a.johansson1/ShellContextMenu.zip).

I have no idea how to use it, or even if it works. That's left as an exercise for the reader. But there is a lot you can learn from this if you dig into the code.