# How to display the default right-drag context menu (copy/move/create shortcut, etc.)

Tags: c#, windows, contextmenu

Displaying the default right-click context menu is pretty straightforward and fairly well documented here and elsewhere on the web.

I based one largely off of Andreas Johansson's framework 
[How to show system menu of a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183811/how-to-show-system-menu-of-a-file-in-c-sharp)
http://windows-tech.info/19/e5ad8751fc63816b.php).

My app provides a simple explorer-like view to display some custom attributes (thanks Windows for getting rid of IColumn).  The right click context menu works great.

However, I'm now finding myself really wanting the right-drag context menu (Copy here, Move here, Create shortcuts here, cancel, plus any additional add on handlers like TSVN).

I assumed that there would be an additional flag I could add to QueryContextMenu uFlags, but alas I don't see one.  Is there an alternative to QueryContextMenu to extract the menu items that are relevant to the right-drag menus?